# Request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous... Really?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Consider the following, minimal example:

```
struct T { void operator()() { } };
struct S { void operator()(int) { } };

struct U: T, S {
    U(): T{}, S{} { }
    //using T::operator();
    //using S::operator();
};

int main() {
    U u;
    u(42);
}
```

It compiles as it is with [clang 3.8](https://godbolt.org/g/PhnwBh).
Anyway, it fails to compile with [GCC 6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/PUWcem) with the error:

> 12 : error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous

Note that [GCC 6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/4Usf0W) works fine if the `using` directives are uncommented.
As far as I know, there is no reason for such an error and it seems that clang is the one that works as expected.

Before to open a bug to *I don't know who*, I'd like to ask if there is something that I missed.
In other terms, to give an error is the right behavior in this case or it's an error for itself?

Comment: Really. There is no overloading across scopes in C++.

Comment: I think gcc is right.  Overload selection is usually done after it figures out the scope.  In this case, it can't select the base class I question due to the ambiguity

Comment: @T.C. Right, wrong tag. Anyway, the call to `operator()` is not ambiguous because of the parameters. Am I wrong?

Comment: I thought that the scope in this case was `U` due to the `using` declarations.

Comment: If the using statements are there, it works, and the scope is the struct U.  Without the using clauses, it should fail due to ambiguity

Comment: @DaveS Uhm, I got it, it makes sense, haven't thought about that... Would you add an answer with the details?